# Use existing service account for running job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am currently using `emmisary-ingress` in my namespace `newcluster`.I am setting up crds using the following [crds.yaml file](https://app.getambassador.io/yaml/emissary/3.3.0/emissary-crds.yaml). In this i have only changed the hardcoded namespace.

By looking into following section of code, i came to know that the service name is `emissary-apiext`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: emissary-apiext
  namespace: newcluster
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: emissary-apiext
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl_apply_-f_emissary-apiext.yaml
    app.kubernetes.io/name: emissary-apiext
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: emissary-apiext
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: emissary-apiext
    app.kubernetes.io/name: emissary-apiext
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: emissary-apiext
```

Now in following job from which i am trying to create one yaml of type `KubernetesEndpointResolver`, i simply mentioned the `serviceAccountName: emissary-apiext` and installed it with helm.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ template "name" . }}
    chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}
    component: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-job-kube-resolvers
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: emissary-apiext
      containers:
        - name: cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd
          image: "bitnami/kubectl:1.23.10-debian-11-r9"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd
              mountPath: /etc/cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd
              readOnly: true
          command: ["kubectl", "apply", "-f", "/etc/cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd", "-n", "newcluster"]
      volumes:
        - name: cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd
          configMap:
            name: cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

the configmap having yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  name: cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd
data: 
  crds.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
    kind: KubernetesEndpointResolver
    metadata:
      name: {{ .Release.Namespace }}-endpoint
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: emissary-apiext
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl_apply_-f_emissary-apiext.yaml
        app.kubernetes.io/name: emissary-apiext
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: emissary-apiext
```

The error i am from job is :

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "getambassador.io/v3alpha1, Resource=kubernetesendpointresolvers", GroupVersionKind: "getambassador.io/v3alpha1, Kind=KubernetesEndpointResolver"
Name: "newcluster-endpoint", Namespace: "newcluster"
from server for: "/etc/cert-manager-setup-certificates-crd/crds.yaml": 
kubernetesendpointresolvers.getambassador.io "newcluster-endpoint" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:newcluster:emissary-apiext" 
cannot get resource "kubernetesendpointresolvers" in API group "getambassador.io" in the namespace "newcluster"
```

Comment: Service and ServiceAccount are two very different objects.  If you're deploying this using Helm, I might often expect the ServiceAccount to be deployed as part of the same chart.

Comment: @DavidMaze i tried seperately too with kubectl.making seperate charts. still same  issue

Comment: What is the ServiceAccount named; do you have the YAML that creates it?  To reiterate. that is a different object from the Service you show in the question.

Comment: it is in same crds.yaml file with same name ```emissary-apiext```